# How do I add an icon in the address bar for a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm not sure how to do it, and the documentation doesn't seem to make this quite obvious.

I tried making a `background_page` and putting `chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);` inside it, but that doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to use the `browser_action` icon because the icon merely reflects the status of the plugin, but it is not a button for performing any actions.

How do I add the page_action's icon inside the address bar for any page/tab at all times?

EDIT: Here's my manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "My Very First Extension :D",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Awesomeness",
    "background_page": "background.html",

    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["mmm.js"]
    }]
}
```

Where icon.png is a 19x19 pixel PNG graphic. Here's the background.html source, where I'm trying to make the page_action icon appear for all tabs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### I see two issues with your code.

1. You cannot use inline script blocks in your background page -- js code can only be run from a linked script (like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>`).  This is because of the [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution).
2. As noted in abraham's answer, since you want the icon to appear for all pages, you should use browser_action, not page_action.  According to [Google's pageAction documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#tips):

   > Don't use page actions for features that make sense for most pages.
   >   Use browser actions instead.

   Icons for page actions appear inside the omnibar (Chrome's address bar), while icons for browser actions appear as a toolbar button next to the omnibar.  Either can be used to reflect the status of the plugin and as an action button.

### Solutions

To get the icon to appear, you have to call: `chrome.pageAction.show(tabId)`.  However, you cannot just call this from a content script, because chrome.pageAction.show() must be passed the tabId, and tabId is retrieved from chrome.tabs, and [chrome.tabs is not accessible from content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

To add a browser action button and define it's behavior when clicked, define the browser_action element in your manifest.json file ...

```
"browser_action": {
   "default_title": "action description",
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
}
```

... and place this code in your background script:

```
// Define behavior when browser action icon is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   // executed when the user clicks on the browser action icon
});
```

**Or**, if you want to go against convention and use a pageAction, you can use the manifest.json code from your question and place the following into your background script:

```
// Show page action icon in omnibar.
function showPageAction( tabId, changeInfo, tab ) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
};
// Call the above function when the url of a tab changes.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(showPageAction);
```

For further research, check out the source code of some of their [sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you want a content-script to show a page action icon, he (the content-script) can't do that, but, he can send a message to the background.js to do it (background.js is allowed to show page action icons)

content script (eg. foo.js):

```
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "showIcon"}, function(response) {});
```

background.js:

```
   // Received a message from content script
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {               
       if (request.action == "showIcon") {
          chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
       }
   });
```

Comment: I think the new answer is worth more than 10 upvotes !

Answer (score 1):

Use a `browser_action` icon. `page_action` and `browser_action` are the same and provide the same functionality except that `page_action`s can be enabled only for specific pages. If you don't want the `browser_action` to act like a button than don't have it do anything.

Comment: I can't even get the icon to show up for the page_action on any tab though. How do you do it?

Comment: `chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id)` is they way to do it. You will have to show us more of your code to debug that further though.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my question with the manifest.json and the background_page.

Comment: `tab.id` is not being set so it doesn't know what tab to show the `page_action`

Comment: So what's the standard way to make the `page_action` icon appear for all pages? (Wish it was simple like `browser_action`s!)

Comment: There is no standard or easy way because `page_action` isn't designed to be used on all pages. That is what `browser_actions`s are for. If you really want to you have to get a list of all the tabs and call `chrome.pageAction.show(id)` for every single tab.

Comment: Hmmmm... Well it'd be nice to have page_actions reflected on all pages. This is better than browser_action sometimes because having a useless button that does nothing defeats the purpose of "button". It messes up the metaphors being used in the UI. I just want the icon visible like a page_action so people know that the plugin is active, but so they don't think clicking it will do something. I shall figure it out and post the answer.

Comment: `page_actions` and `browser_actions` are both "bottons". The only difference is one is page specific and the other is browser global. `browser_actions` can be hidden by users if they choose so that might be the best choice.

Comment: I know, I get that. I still want my `page_action` to appear at all times because it doesn't **look** like a button. In older versions of chrome, the ability to have page actions on all pages was a standard feature.