# Chrome extension page action appearing outside of address bar

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wrote a Chrome Extension page action, with the following implementation:

﻿﻿In manifest.json:

```
  "permissions" : [
    "declarativeContent"
  ],
```

In background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlMatches: 'www\.somewebsite\.com/(translate|revise)/' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

I noticed that in most Chrome browsers, the page action icon appears correctly inside the address and only appears when the matching page is met:

[image: Page action appearing as expected]

However, in some browsers recently page actions started appearing as enabled/disabled browser actions, i.e. outside the address bar, which is a lot clumsier because the whole idea around page actions icons is that they appear if and only if the page is relevant to them.  There is no point showing a disabled page action for most of the time.  Actually, it happened to browsers where it used to work well days ago, like if a Chrome update had some side effects.

[image: Page action appearing like a Browser action]

I presume this is related to some Chrome setting that now shows all extensions there, but is there any way I can force the page action to appear consistently in the address bar and only appear when it can be really useful?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It appears like this is the result of a new update to Chrome, with the developers probably reasoning that most users would not know that they had extensions installed otherwise.

Link to announcement: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-extensions/upcoming/chromium-extensions/7As9MKhav5E/dNiZDoSCCQAJ

It doesn't look like extension developers can do anything about this, but I really hope Google reverts this change.

Comment: I really hope Google reconsiders it and it is reversed. It defeats the whole purpose of page actions, which are designed not to be intrusive.

Comment: Announcement: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-extensions/upcoming$20ui$20change/chromium-extensions/7As9MKhav5E/dNiZDoSCCQAJ

Comment: Corrected link of the announcement, thank you for the pointer:  https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/chromium-extensions/upcoming/chromium-extensions/7As9MKhav5E/dNiZDoSCCQAJ

Comment: I agree with Pep, it was a lot more useful and user-friendly to build multiple extensions. This is no longer possible. you are forced to clutter your entire browser screen. Bleegh. I seriously hope they consider reverting this change. I dislike it very much.

Comment: I wrote this in the announcement: "Chrome should determine if the page action icon is already visible and, if not, it should show it within the address bar as in the past.  I agree that showing two icons for a page action is a clumsy UX but since Chrome has all information on what is visible in the UI, it should ensure that, for a page action extension, at least one icon appears wither withing the address bar or outside.
Ensuring that one active page icon is visible further reinforces your goal of security by user awareness and improves usability for clickable page action icons."

Comment: Same here of course! I think this will be as an option/flag the user should active it from `Chrome://flags` page in the next releases. The question is, has this update released on Chrome Canary as well?

Comment: Just make it an explicit option or permission which users need to enable. Besides the ability to hide the entire icon (which is just really a mandatory feature Google), it's way more valuable to also be able to show icons in the address bar. I think optionality and user choice is key to better functionality and more user awareness.

Comment: Important link: Google is collecting feedback **strictly in the form of links to extensions + use cases hampered by the change** at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597657 Please exercise restraint and conform to that specific discussion format.