# put chrome extension icon in the url bar

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a button in the toolbar and I'd like tu put it in the url bar next to the bookmarks one.

Here it's my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "__MSG_appName__",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
    "default_locale": "en",
        "icons": {
          "128": "icon_128.png"
        },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome extension page action appearing outside of address bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755297/chrome-extension-page-action-appearing-outside-of-address-bar)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction), not a browser action.

However be advised Chrome is transitioning to showing page action extension icons on the toolbar as well:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/google-chrome-49-moves-all-your-extension-icons-501384.shtml
https://chrome.googleblog.com/2016/01/new-year-new-chrome.html

Comment: I use page action and it is still in the toolbar. Google Now is gone, icons in the address bar are gone...